# Table is mutating, trigger may not see it

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

There is no error when I create the trigger. But when I fire it, an error message displays that the table is mutating. How do I solve this problem of table mutating?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tgr_invoice
AFTER UPDATE OF discharge_date
ON Admission
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
doc_fee NUMBER(5);
nights_stayed NUMBER(4);
room_price NUMBER(5);
room_fee NUMBER(9);
med_fee NUMBER(7, 2);
units_prescribed NUMBER(3);
price_per_unit NUMBER(7, 2);
total_fee NUMBER(8,2);
BEGIN
SELECT consult_fee INTO doc_fee     
FROM Doctor
WHERE staff_id IN (SELECT seen_by FROM Admission
WHERE patient_id = :NEW.patient_id
AND admission_date = :NEW.admission_date);

SELECT (discharge_date - admission_date) INTO nights_stayed 
FROM Admission 
WHERE patient_id = :NEW.patient_id
AND admission_date = :NEW.admission_date;

SELECT room_price INTO room_price 
FROM Room
WHERE room_no IN (SELECT room_no FROM Admission
WHERE patient_id = :NEW.patient_id
AND admission_date = :NEW.admission_date);

SELECT units_prescribed INTO units_prescribed 
FROM Prescription
WHERE patient_id = :NEW.patient_id
AND prescription_date = :NEW.admission_date;

SELECT price_per_unit INTO price_per_unit 
FROM Medicine
WHERE med_id IN (SELECT med_id FROM Prescription 
WHERE patient_id = :NEW.patient_id
AND prescription_date = :NEW.Admission_date);

room_fee := room_price * nights_stayed;
med_fee := units_prescribed * price_per_unit;
total_fee := room_fee + doc_fee + med_fee;

INSERT INTO Invoice VALUES(seq_inv_no.NEXTVAL, :NEW.patient_id, 
:NEW.admission_date, doc_fee, room_fee, med_fee, total_fee);
END;
/
```

When I update the admission table and input the discharge date, an error arises 'table SYSTEM.ADMISSION is mutating, trigger/function may not see it'

Comment: It would help if you described the logic you are trying to implement.  Sample data and desired results help.

Comment: You should not create any user tables or other objects in `SYSTEM` (or any other Oracle system schema). Create a user for your application and create your objects there.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be more proper to derive the values from assignments as a result of operations among :NEW or :OLD values of columns of tables on which DB trigger is created rather than using SELECT statments for a row-level trigger . So, consider using the following code block :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tgr_invoice AFTER UPDATE OF discharge_date ON Admission
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    doc_fee NUMBER(5);
    nights_stayed NUMBER(4);
    room_price NUMBER(5);
    room_fee NUMBER(9);
    med_fee NUMBER(7, 2);
    units_prescribed NUMBER(3);
    price_per_unit NUMBER(7, 2);
    total_fee NUMBER(8,2);
BEGIN
 SELECT consult_fee 
   INTO doc_fee     
   FROM Doctor
  WHERE staff_id = :NEW.seen_by;

 nights_stayed := :NEW.discharge_date - :NEW.admission_date; 

 SELECT room_price 
   INTO room_price 
   FROM Room
  WHERE room_no = :NEW.room_no;

 SELECT units_prescribed 
   INTO units_prescribed 
   FROM Prescription
  WHERE patient_id = :NEW.patient_id
    AND prescription_date = :NEW.admission_date;

 SELECT price_per_unit INTO price_per_unit 
   FROM Medicine
  WHERE med_id IN (SELECT med_id 
                     FROM Prescription 
                    WHERE patient_id = :NEW.patient_id
                      AND prescription_date = :NEW.Admission_date);

 room_fee := room_price * nights_stayed;
 med_fee := units_prescribed * price_per_unit;
 total_fee := room_fee + doc_fee + med_fee;

 INSERT INTO Invoice 
 VALUES(seq_inv_no.NEXTVAL, :NEW.patient_id, :NEW.admission_date, 
        doc_fee, room_fee, med_fee, total_fee);
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it.